# Acquiring Text of a label from scene1 to scene2 Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a simple 2d card game in Unity , While the user is playing the game , certain information is getting captured like (score,tries,time), When the user wins or loses the game then the appropriate scene (game over or Win scene) is getting triggered, in these 2 scenes id like to copy the info from the score, tries, time fields of the game to the appropriate labels of gameOver or Win, But it seems I'm doing something wrong..

I tried to find similar questions on StackOverflow, Youtube, the web; I checked the documentation and I tried different approaches.

Here is the code I'm working with at the moment, which seems totally correct to me, I don't get any errors, just nothings appears in the labels.

```
'''
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class win_results : MonoBehaviour
{
    // public options script;

    public Text score_final_text;
    public Text tries_final_text;
    public Text time_final_text;

    public void player_win_results() 
    {
        // script = a.getComponent<options>();

        if (options.user_lvl_choice=="easy")
        {
            GameObject tries_final = GameObject.Find("tries_text_lvl1"); //finds the object named score_results 
            tries_final_text.text = tries_final.GetComponent<Text>().text + "a"; //gets the Text property of it.

            GameObject time_final = GameObject.Find("TimeCounter_lvl1"); //finds the object named score_results 
            time_final_text.text = time_final.GetComponent<Text>().text + "a"; //gets the Text property of it.

            GameObject score_final = GameObject.Find("score_lvl1"); //finds the object named score_results 
            score_final_text.text = score_final.GetComponent<Text>().text + "a"; //gets the Text property of it.
        }
        else if (options.user_lvl_choice == "hard")
        {
            GameObject tries_final = GameObject.Find("tries_text_lvl2"); //finds the object named score_results 
            tries_final_text.text = tries_final.GetComponent<Text>().text + "a"; //gets the Text property of it.

            GameObject time_final = GameObject.Find("TimeCounter_lvl2"); //finds the object named score_results 
            time_final_text.text = time_final.GetComponent<Text>().text + "a"; //gets the Text property of it.

            GameObject score_final = GameObject.Find("score_lvl2"); //finds the object named score_results 
            score_final_text.text = score_final.GetComponent<Text>().text + "a"; //gets the Text property of it.
        }
    }
```

As the code above shows I'm using `GameObject.Find` as the documentation states, I have double checked the names and typos, the scripts are correctly attached, I get no errors in the output, just nothing happens.

As you can see above I have added an extra "a" character at the end for debugging purposes, the "a" character also doesn't appear in the output, meaning that the `gameObject` find doesn't work correctly in my example.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a scene without the second parameter

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("scene2");
```

The old scene will be destroyed, all the GameObjects in that scene will also be destroyed except you've called DontDestroyOnLoad on it.

So if you haven't done this job yet, what you get in the new scene are empty data. You can print the values to check.

The easiest way to pass data through scenes is use static field. Create a class and add some static fields:

```
class Global
{
     public static string user_lvl_choice;
     public static string tries_final;
     ....
}
```

Then you can set or get these values from any scene.

```
Global.user_lvl_choice = "easy"
print(Global.user_lvl_choice);
```

Read more:

- [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)
- [SceneManager.LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)
- [Object.DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

Comment: Solved brother , thanks lot for the time and effort. Thumbs up

Comment: Since Text is a gameObject , i put the 3 Texts fileds on the dontDestroyOnLoad, but still i dont get output , still investigating

Comment: If you don't know how to use DontDestroyOnLoad, read the document or take some research, not easy to explain in a few words.

Comment: You can save the string value (not the Text object), then set them to the Text object in the new scene.

Comment: I used static fields and everything is good mate, also i understood how the dontdestroyonload works. thanks mate.